# Creating jQuery global variables for input form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, local-variables

I have what I believe to be a simple question, but I'm stuck:

I am trying to validate a credit card number in an input field.

I have a switch statement which picks up the type of credit card, and executes a validation function depending on the card detected.

The problem is, I'm struggling to insert a variable within my card validation function which represents the real-time card number (when the document loads, the field is empty).

Here's the HTML:

```
<form name="cardDetailsFrom">
<label>Enter Card Number</label>
<input type="text" id="cardNumber" name="cardNumber" />
</form>
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
$("#cardNumber").keyup(function(){
var cardNumber = $(this).val();
});


function validateAmericanExpress(){
   if(cardNumber==//Rest of code doesn't work because can't pick up the local variable
   };
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated by a jQuery newbie. I'm trying to avoid using the standard plugins though. Thanks!

Comment: You never call your `validateAmericanExpress()` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't jQuery specific, its just basic Javascript function calling.

```
$('#cardNumber').on('keyup',function(){
    validateAmericanExpress(this.value);
});

function validateAmericanExpress(cardNumber){
    if(cardNumber === // whatever, now the if logic will work
}
```

Basically, you are calling the function with the value on each keyup, and passing the value into the function as `cardNumber` to be used within that function.

This is better than using a large-scope variable because it doesn't require allocation of cache from the browser, increasing efficiency and speed. More importantly, it helps avoid possible collisions (multiple items setting the global variable in conflict) and makes code much more readable and easier to maintain.

**Efficient use of possible returns**

You can even make the code more appropriately-located as such:

```
$('#cardNumber').on('keyup',function(){
    if(validateAmericanExpress(this.value)){ // this checks if the call returned true
        // happy times
    } else {
        // show error message that says invalid
    }
});

function validateAmericanExpress(cardNumber){
    if(cardNumber === 'whatever'){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or even better, use ternary!

```
$('#cardNumber').on('keyup',function(){
    validateAmericanExpress(this.value) ? alert('correct') : alert('error');
});

function validateAmericanExpress(cardNumber){
    cardNumber === 'whatever' ? return true :  return false;
}
```

Super efficiency status! If you want to learn more about ternary / conditional operators, [check out this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

**Make function more extensible**

Lastly, your cardnumber validator is probably just checking that its a specific number sequence right? You can probably do it without a function call:

```
$('#cardNumber').on('keyup',function(){
    var regex = '/^3[47][0-9]{13}$/';
    regex.test(this.value) ? alert('correct') : alert('error');
});
```

That is for testing for AmEx. If you are testing a variety of credit cards, you can use the function with a parameter, and make it crazy generic!

```
$('#cardNumber').on('keyup',function(){
    validateCreditCard(this.value),'amex') ? alert('correct') : alert('error');
});

function validateCreditCard(cardNumber,type){
    var regex;

    switch(type){
        case 'amex':
            regex = '/^3[47][0-9]{13}$/';
            break;
        case 'visa':
            regex = '/^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$/';
            break;
        case 'mastercard':
            regex = '/^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/';
            break;
        default:
            regex = '/d{16,17}$/'; // just checking it is all numeric and appropriate length 
    }

    return regex.test(cardNumber);
}
```

This will allow you to test all credit cards unilaterally, especially if instead of passing a string like `'amex'` you use the value of a radio button selection. If you want more information about the regex strings for all the cards, [check out this reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html).

Comment: efficiency and speed with using global instead of local variables is negligible in most cases, do to preprocessing of javascript in modern browsers - in fact, sometimes using a global can be more efficient - the main reasoning for not cluttering up a scope is avoiding variable collisions that are hard to spot and for other reasons related to good structured coding

Comment: added additional benefits of local vs global. and you are right, the difference here is miniscule, but dont diminish the gains, no matter how negligible they might be. pennies become dollars, and keeping speed in the mind helps to create better coding habits, so its more about the overarching principle.

Comment: This response is awesome. You've made my day so much easier. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

using a var inside a scope limits it to that scope

use PlantTheIdea's answer or just remove the var and make a new `var cardNumer;` outside

Comment: yeah the thing is, u dont need to declare a variable outside for this kind of simplicity. why suck up any extra cache when you don't need to?

Comment: sure, but i think its of more value to teach him about scopes then to just tell him your preferred way without giving him the reasoning behind it. But yes, using the global scope is to be avoided

Comment: good point. i edited my answer to explain the reason i avoided the variable usage, and provided some efficiency techniques as well.